# Inserting commas into a text file to create a .csv

Tags: csv, txt

I have a text file which is the output from a measurement machine. The file looks like:

```
  X    3.49992    3.50000    0.00100   -0.00100   -0.00008                -      Position1
Dst    1.25003    1.25000    0.00200   -0.00200    0.00003                 +     Position2
  Z    2.26010    2.25900    0.00200   -0.00200    0.00110                 +++   Position3
  Y    1.54378    1.55900    0.00500   -0.00500   -0.01522   -0.01022  <<<<      Position4
  Y    1.82344    1.80900    0.00500   -0.00500    0.01444    0.00944      >>>>  Position5

etc.
```

I would like to be able to create a csv file that can easily be imported into JMP for analysis.

The rows of text have no delimitators, I had thought about putting commas in specific positions/columns within the row:- (7,18,29,39,50,61,71,81).

So it would look something like this:

```
  X    ,3.49992    ,3.50000    ,0.00100   ,-0.00100   ,-0.00008 ,       ,     -     ,Position1
Dst    ,1.25003    ,1.25000    ,0.00200   ,-0.00200   , 0.00003 ,       ,      +     ,Position2
  Z    ,2.26010    ,2.25900    ,0.00200   ,-0.00200   , 0.00110 ,       ,      +++   ,Position3
  Y    ,1.54378    ,1.55900    ,0.00500   ,-0.00500   ,-0.01522 , -0.01022  ,<<<<     ,Position4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: I am able to do it using excel, but I would like to script it in python.

Comment: I'm pretty much a complete beginner, apart from trying a few things I've seen on here, I'm at the start.

Comment: And yes, on a Windows PC.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.